# How to create link to an embedded image in doxygen markdown

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I couldn't find any answer to what I'm looking for on SO (or anywhere else).  I have an embedded image in my markdown file to be consumed by doxygen which looks like the following:

```
# 2. Example Markdown {#exMd}

This is a test to show an image

![imgDef]

[imgDef]: @ref SettingsValidationCollaborationDiagram.jpg "Diagram Caption"

## Some Other Section

This is a test to put a link to the image above.  See [here](@ref imgDef)
```

See screenshot below for what I want to happen:

[image: example:]

If I click on here, then it would take me to the part of the page with the original image visible.  I couldn't figure out a way to make an anchor, or some other mechanism to create something I could link to near the image.

Obviously, the existing code causes me errors, but I don't know how to insert a link to an image that doesn't just embed the image at the location.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In case not the current version (1.8.15) can you try this? Can you post a small complete example showing your problem.

Comment: @albert Added more detail to the question.  I'm using 1.8.14, but that won't make a difference if I don't know the proper syntax to do what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no link possible to the image in this way.
This said there is a possibility by means of the `\anchor` command (I've placed some extra comments in HTML comments in the example):

```
# 2. Example Markdown {#exMd}

This is a test to show an image

\anchor imgDef <!-- added line -->
![imgDef]

[imgDef]: SettingsValidationCollaborationDiagram.jpg "Diagram Caption" <!-- no need for the @ref here -->

## Some Other Section

This is a test to put a link to the image above.  See [here](@ref imgDef)
```

A small addition based on the comment, from the documentation:

> \anchor
>
> This command places an invisible, named anchor into the documentation to which you can refer with the \ref command.

Comment: Thanks @albert !!! I couldn't find any info about how to use the anchors, but your solution works perfectly for what I'm trying to do!